# Inner function calling parent function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How can an inner function call a parent function after it has expired?

```
setTimeout(main, 2000);
function main(){
    /* .... code */
    setTimeout(console.log("hello after 5 seconds"), 5000);
}
```

The intended action is to print `hello after 5 seconds` in 5 seconds (7 total); with the above code it prints it in 2 seconds.

Comment: I assure you, it **will** happen :)

Comment: Is it you final code? You have sobre problems...

Comment: Your `function1()` code does not do anything, so how do you know it doesn't get called?

Comment: `function1(){ return string; }` is not valid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `setTimeout` function references.  With `setTimeout(console.log("hello after 5 seconds"), 5000);`, you call `console.log` *immediately*.  Any time you write `()` after a function name, you're invoking it.

`console.log` returns *undefined*, which is what is passed to `setTimeout`.  It just ignores the *undefined* value and does nothing.  (And it doesn't throw any errors.)

If you need to pass parameters to your callback function, there are a few different ways to go.

Anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('...');
}, 5000);
```

Return a function:

```
function logger(msg) {
    return function() {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}

// now, whenever you need to do a setTimeout...
setTimeout(logger('...'), 5000);
```

This works because invoking `logger` simply returns a new anonymous function that closes over `msg`.  The returned function is what is actually passed to `setTimeout`, and when the callback is fired, it has access to `msg` via the closure.

Comment: Answer completely reworked to address updated, clarified question.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understood what you want. Take a look:

```
var main = function(){
    console.log("foo");
    var function1 = function( string ) {
        console.log("function1: " + string);
    };
    var function2 = function() {
        console.log( "hadouken!" );
    };
    // you will need to use a closure to call the function
    // that you want with parameters
    // if you dont have parameters, just pass the function itself
    setTimeout(function(){ function1("bar") }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function2, 6000);
}
setTimeout(main, 2000);
```

Or:

```
function main(){
    console.log("foo");
    function function1( string ) {
        console.log("function1: " + string);
    };
    function function2() {
        console.log( "hadouken!" );
    };
    // you will need to use a closure to call the function
    // that you want with parameters
    // if you dont have parameters, just pass the function itself
    setTimeout(function(){ function1("bar") }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function2, 6000);
}
setTimeout(main, 2000);
```

I usually prefer the first sintax.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/65VsV/

Answer (score 1):

It [works](http://jsfiddle.net/82yVn/)! You miss word `function`.

```
setTimeout(main, 1000);

function main() {
    function function1 () { alert(1); };
    setTimeout(function1, 1000);
}​
```